# Fix scrollTo page flicker in wordpress child theme?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scrollto

When you click the menu items, the page flickers before it does the animated scrolling. It seems I need to prevent the default href action of the menu items, but I can't find where to do that.

http://teratomic.org/

I can't find 'scrollto' anywhere in the theme code. Heres's what I've found in the theme's Header.php at least... but still can't find where to put the preventdefault

```
<ul class="navigation">
                                <?php if (has_nav_menu( 'header-menu' )) { ?>
                                <?php
                                   $the_menu = array(
                                    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                                    'container'       => 'ul',
                                    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
                                    'echo'            => true,
                                    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                                    'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                                    'depth'           => 0
                                   );

                                   wp_nav_menu( $the_menu );
                                ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a problem with default href behaviour you should in your function before scrollTo place preventDefault so it should look like:

```
$("yourmenulink").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
scrollTo....

});
```

Comment: I'm not an wordpress user but you should put it in the same place where you put your scrolling code.

Comment: I didn't make the scrolling code, the theme author did (unresponsive to emails). I've updated the question to include code I've found that SEEMS like where the scollto would be referenced, but I don't see it.

Comment: Fixed it. Found the code in the theme's Footer php. For those looking for the same thing it was jQuery('.navigation li a')